# How page knows where to go in this aspx code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code in login page

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
        }
    }
```

and when i run the code, if i entered a wrong username and password, the page tells me it is wrong, and if i entered a correct username and password, the page makes me login .

#### where is the code of all that vertification?

#### if you waant the html (aspx) tell me please

Comment: The control `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login LoginUser` is doing the heavy lifting. Have a [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Look in the code behind for the Login.aspx page (Login.aspx.cs)

Comment: This is the code behind my friend, it is all the code behind

Comment: Nope.  See the `partial` keyword?  There is another file that contains the rest of the class.

Comment: @The other `partial` class contains this `protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink RegisterHyperLink;` `protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login LoginUser;`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this application is using [Membership API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) and the Login control is automatically bound to a specific [Membership API Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx3h274z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You could see this by looking the web config file where you would see a [related authentication section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Check [this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx) to see how the login controls work in asp.net.

Hope I helped!